# share a component or use multiple components in angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular material for an admin template project. there are many tables in my template and all of them have sorting, pagination, selection and filter. should I use a single shared component for all of my tables or configure every table individually? Another way is to separate pagination, sorting, filter and selection as components.

Comment: Can you use https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview ?

Comment: of course I'm using that. the question is, what is the most optimized way to have many tables and configure their pagination sorting filter and select.

Comment: Create a Table component which has table pagination and sort and pass `@Input` to the components the configuration you want to set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of thumb says that if you intend to change the default look and feel (now or in the future) and if you want consistent design, you should wrap it in a shared component. This way you have only one place to make future changes.

If you're not going to change the default material design apperaince then I would say no to a singlre shared component as material design table already is.

Comment: so there is no standard policy for that in angular material?